# handle checkbox data and store in a state/variable

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

How can I store the selected value in another state and stop unchecking the value when I select another button?

```
const Notifications = () => {


data:[
{id:1, name:apple, notification:{id:1,msg:"hi"}, {id=2,msg:"hlo"}},
{id:2, name:banana, notification:{id:13,msg:"hi"}, {id=3,msg:"hlo"}}
{id:3 ,name:mango, notification:{id:14,msg:"hi"}, {id=34,msg:"hlo"}},
{id:4, name:grape, notification:{id:15,msg:"hi"}, {id=341,msg:"hlo"}},
{id:5, name:carrot, notification:{id:16,msg:"hi"}, {id=4,msg:"hlo"}},
]

  const onCheckedValue = (e) => {
        const { checked, value } = e.target;
        if (checked) {
            setCheckedData([...checkedData, value]);
        } else {
            setCheckedData(checkedData.filter((item) => item !== value));
        }
    };  

return(
<>
{data.map(d => {
<Button onClick=(setActive(true))>
{d.name}

</Button>

})}
```

//render the notifications when I clicked on the button I want to store the checked value in a state with respect to the selected button and checked notification.

```
{active ? 
data.notifications.map((notification) => (
           <div className="checkbox">
           <Checkbox
           onChange={onCheckedValue}
           value={notification}
            />
          /div>
}
</>

)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [React Use State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). You'll want to define a variable and a state setter for that variable like so:
`const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);`

Then when you click or un-click a checkbox, you can call `setSelected` with the updated `selected` value. I instantiated `selected` as an empty array in my example, so you'd `arr.push(new value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second block of code is where there are issues.

You are attempting to access properties on `data`, but that is an array and you cannot access the properties of the objects inside of it like that.

You will need to loop over the array or access an index of the array directly in order to access `notifications`.

As a side note, you are attempting to use the ternary operator to conditionally render (`?`), but not supplying the second argument after the `:`.  I gave it a value of `null` so that it doesn't render anything if not `active`.

That could look something like this:

```
// I don't know where active comes from, but I'll assume that's correct.
{active ? (
  data.map((item) => (
    <div className="checkbox">
      <Checkbox
        onChange={onCheckedValue}
        checked={!!checkedData.find(name => name === item.name)}
        value={item.name}
      />
    </div>
  ))) : null
}
```

In this example, I map over `data` and create a `Checkbox` for each item in the array.  I don't know if that's what you want as it's unclear.  However, with your `onCheckedValue` function, it will make updates to the `checkedData` array.

You should pass the prop `checked` to control the checkbox's state.  I set the `checked` value to the return of `checkedData.find()`, and used the double-bang (`!!`) operator to coerce it into a Boolean value (true or false).

The `find` operation will be looking to see if the `data[i].name` matches any value in the `checkedData` array, since you are storing the object's `name` property in the `checkedData` array. If it finds nothing, it will be `!!undefined` which will evaluate to `false`, and if it does find it, it will be `!!"banana"` which evaluates to `true`.